# How To Play Music From Headless Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, audio, google-chrome-headless

I wanted to make an app that plays Spotify Music in headless selenium, but it's not playing the song at all. Is a script to click a button working properly ?
Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    executable_path = "chromedriver.exe"
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--no-default-browser-check')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-default-apps')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, options=options)
    driver.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Falbum%2F0KXLHn67Go118RT48pTHXm')
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('my email')
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('my password')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="login-button"]')).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-green.false'))
```

When I tried to run it i got this

````
[0113/001403.264:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'https://www.google.rs/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-5784146-31&cid=434111290.1578870843&jid=1740149161&_v=j79&z=670730096&slf_rd=1&random=2105731225' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https://i.imgur.com https://d2mv8tnci56s9d.cloudfront.net https://profile-images.scdn.co https://aci.scdn.co https://graph.facebook.com https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com https://www.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net data: https://accounts.scdn.co".
", source: https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Falbum%2F0KXLHn67Go118RT48pTHXm (0)
[0113/001407.421:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Falbum%2F0KXLHn67Go118RT48pTHXm (0)
[0113/001407.819:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://open.spotify.com/album/0KXLHn67Go118RT48pTHXm (0)
[0113/001409.755:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://subscription.omnithrottle.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://open.spotify.com/album/0KXLHn67Go118RT48pTHXm (0)
[0113/001410.001:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) HarmonyError: Cannot perform command; local player is disabled.", source: https://open.spotify.com/album/0KXLHn67Go118RT48pTHXm (0) ```
````

Comment: Have you tried with normal selenium and it worked?

Comment: @shimo It works using normal selenium, but not in headless

Comment: When you ran it not in headless mode, did you use the same chrome options? I would guess, that one of them is blocking the player (as the last log says `"Uncaught (in promise) HarmonyError: Cannot perform command; local player is disabled."`)

Comment: You can safely ignore the `SameSite` warnings, they should be unrelated to this issue.

Comment: @Jonah even without them it's not working, I guess spotify doesn't allow headless browser